# AS3 - Get string values

Tags: actionscript-3, string

I need to get the values of **img= via= title=**. Is there a smart way to do it or does it just require a lot of **split and join**?

> http://www.example.com/#section/img=http://example.org/mypic.jpg/via=example.org/blog/pictures/title=Hello-World

The content will be always different.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried using regular expressions? It seems like the perfect fit for this.

Basically I would separate the `http://www.example.com/#section/` from `img=http://example.org/mypic.jpg/via=example.org/blog/pictures/title=Hello-World`

then use another regex to split the three different values most uris use another character that can act as a separator. look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme

> Semicolon:
>   key1=value1;key2=value2;key3=value3
>
> Ampersand:
>   key1=value1&key2=value2&key3=value3

this makes creating regular expressions easier, because you look for anything between the separators.

you would then end up with an array of three strings 
`key1=value1` `key2=value2`  and `key3=value3` you can do another regex where you separate on the `=` and end up with an array that holds the key/value pair.

If you know your regular expression well, you might be able to do it with fewer expressions.

the tool I always use is http://regexpal.com to craft my expressions. but you might be able to find something in http://regexlib.com/ though they probably utilize the `&` or `;`

Comment: How to get the value of **title=** ? For the rest I'm using this code: `var inbetween:RegExp = /img=(.*?)\/via/g;
var imgmatch:Object = inbetween.exec(my.text);
var imgpath = imgmatch[1];`